# Do I need to reindex after vacuum full on Postgres 9.4

Tags: postgresql, vacuum

I am using Postgres 9.4.

I just ran vacuum full. I read about the differences between vacuum and vacuum full and considered a lot if I should run vacuum or vacuum full. As far as I can say, I required vacuum full and my db size came down from 48 GB to 24 GB.

Would the old indexes would have become obsolete after vacuum full and do I need to run reindex?

I ran "vacuum full verbose analyze", so analyze is done along with vacuum full.

I read at several places that for Postgres > 9.0, I don't need reindex after vacuum full, but I want to be sure that it is the case.

Comment: Since you have already ran `analyze`, a re-indexing won't be necessary since that itself collects the statistics. Check documentation http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-analyze.html for more information.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

A `REINDEX` immediately after a `VACUUM FULL` is **useless** because `VACUUM FULL` itself rebuilds the indexes.

This is mentioned in the 9.4 documentation in [Recovering Disk Space](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-SPACE-RECOVERY) :

> ...to reclaim the excess disk space it occupies, you will need to use
>   VACUUM FULL, or alternatively CLUSTER or one of the table-rewriting
>   variants of ALTER TABLE. These commands rewrite an entire new copy of
>   the table and **build new indexes for it**.

You are correct that this was not the case before version 9.0, which had  `VACUUM FULL` reimplemented differently.

Up to version 8.4, the reference doc for [VACUUM](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-vacuum.html) mentioned the need to reindex:

> <s>The FULL option does not shrink indexes; a periodic REINDEX is still
>   recommended. In fact, it is often faster to drop all indexes, VACUUM
>   FULL, and recreate the indexes.</s>

But this caveat is now obsolete.